# Equation for a squashed circle with exponential corners

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to define a circle that is sort of squashed in to a square-like shape with exponential(?) curved corners.  Here is an image showing what I'm describing:

[image]

Notice it is a circle at a small size and grows more square-like as it gets larger.  Is there an equation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want a [supercircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) with $x^k+y^k=1$.  A circle has $k=2$.  If you increase $k$, the corners move out.  You would have to increase $k$ with size to get the "sharper corners" you refer to.

Alternately you can make a square and put tangent circles at each corner.  Say you want the square to have a side of $2$ with circles of radius $\frac 14$ in each corner.  The centers of the circle are then at $\left(\pm(2-\frac 14),\pm(2-\frac 14)\right)=(\pm \frac 74, \pm \frac 74). $  The sides are just $x= \pm2, -\frac 74 \le y \le \frac 74$ and the corresponding segments in $y$.  The arcs are $(x\pm \frac 74)^2+(y\pm \frac74)^2=(\frac 14)^2$

Comment: Thanks, this got me pointed in the right direction I think.  I believe what I'm looking for is sometimes called a "supercircle" which is defined by: x = a cos^n(angle) y = a sin^n(angle)  with n being the exponent that defines the shape.

Comment: @CR.:  Yes, a supercircle to a superellipse is like a circle to an ellipse.

Comment: Alright, I got it to work using the Superellipse formula off Wikipedia. x(Θ)=|cosΘ|^2/m * a sgn(cosΘ)  y(Θ)=|sinΘ|^2/n * b sgn(sinΘ)   Thanks!

Comment: @CR.:  Note you should have parentheses around $2/m$ and $2/n$.  Otherwise you would get $\frac 1m|cos \theta|^2$ because of the precedence of operations.